# Naive question about almost complex structures and hermitian metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm sorry if I have another naive question, but I want to understand correctly almost complex structures and hermitian metrics.

Let's have $M$ complex manifold with almost complex structure $J$ and $h$ hermitian metric on the complexified tangent bundle. In particular $h$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear on the left and $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear on the right.

Question: why must it be $h(X,Y)=h(JX,JY)$ for every $X,Y\in TM^{\mathbb{C}}$?
I dont' get this right:
$h(J(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}),J(\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}))=h(i(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}),-i(\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}))=i^2h(\frac{\partial}{\partial z},\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}})=-h(\frac{\partial}{\partial z},\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}})$

Where am I getting this wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$It appears you're "conjugating in the second slot" twice: in the initial expression, and again at the starred step, where the scalar $-i$ factors out as $i$:
$$
h(J(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial z}), J(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}))
  = h(i(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial z}), -i(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}))
  \stackrel{*}{=} i^2h(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial z}, \tfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}})
  = -h(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial z}, \tfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}).
$$

Not totally sure of your notation, but in my experience, this type of snag often results from using the same symbol $h$ to denote both a *complex bilinear* pairing $h^{\Cpx}$ on the complexified tangent bundle, and the restriction of $h^{\Cpx}$ to
$$
T^{1,0}M \times T^{0,1}M \subset TM^{\Cpx} \times TM^{\Cpx},
$$
viewed as an Hermitian pairing on $T^{1,0} M$ via
$$
h(X, Y) = h^{\Cpx} (X, \overline{Y}).
$$
Anyway, if your $h$ is complex bilinear, the starred step is the sign error. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand.. to me $h$ is $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear on the right and $J(\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}})=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$, that's the reason why of the starred step.

Comment: fot $h(\frac{\partial}{\partial z},\frac{\partial}{\partial z})$ it comes out right: $h(J(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}),J(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}))=h(i(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}),i(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}))=-i^2h(\frac{\partial}{\partial z},\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=h(\frac{\partial}{\partial z},\frac{\partial}{\partial z})$

Comment: If $h$ is $\Cpx$-antilinear in the second slot, then your initial expression, which amounts to $h(X, \overline{Y})$, looks suspect. Instead: $$h(JX, JY) = (i)h(X, JY) = (i)(-i) h(X, Y) = h(X, Y).$$

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but I don't understand still.. if $Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$ then $J(Y)=-iY$ and if $h$ is $\mathbb{C}$ antilinear on the second slot when I bring out $-i$ I obtain $i$, from which comes the minus sign..

Comment: If you're viewing $h$ as an Hermitian pairing on $TM$ (possibly identified with $T^{1,0}M$), then you can't put $\partial/\partial\bar{z}$ into the second slot, because that's not a $(1, 0)$ tangent vector. (Your second comment above explains why the signs come out right.) :)